# Best way to heat something in aluminum foil?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Let's say we have a wet piece of paper, wrapped in aluminum foil, that we need to heat up in the fastest and most energy efficient way possible (no flamethrower).

What would that be?

Details regarding the methods would be highly appreciated.

Comment: where did 250C come in the problem? It is not a well defined problem as is.

Answer (score 1):

The microwave answer given above is good, especially if you have only one paper wrapped in foil because it would transfer a large fraction of the energy produced to the sample.  If you have many of these (for example as a step on an assembly line) then immerse it in a hot medium.  This would provide really efficient transfer of heat energy for each sample but at higher overhead.  Since you are targeting 250 C, if you want to use water then it has to be in vapor form.  You can heat the vapor with microwave energy and improve your energy transfer efficiency over a single unit in dry air.  Also, at 250 C the water inside the foil will pressurize the foil if it is sealed, and explode it unless it can hold about [40 atmospheres](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/boiling-point-water-d_926.html).  If unsealed then it will vaporize and you will have your sample immersed in a vapor anyway.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how hot you want it, but a hairdryer or heat gun would be quick, but not very energy efficient while it was blowing - but it turns on and off quickly so might be efficient by not having to be on for long.

edit - ok for 250 degrees C - heat gun probably not hot enough.

I would put an oven on at close to max temp and put the foil in, but even then that may not be hot enough for you....

Comment: 250+ c on the inside

Comment: ok probably not hot enough.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a microwave at the right power, and it will quickly heat up withouth burning (and heat whatever is inside). But do not try this at home. Too much power and you will get the microwave oven on flames.

Comment: Wouldn't the Al foil act as a Faraday cage?

Comment: no because it is too thin, a metal bowl will. You can check here: http://science.howstuffworks.com/aluminum-foil-in-the-microwave.htm

Comment: Take it out of the foil, heat it, and put it back in?

Comment: @mmesser314 I'd use a flamethrower, but the OP stated not to.

Answer (score 0):

Heat a batch of [high temperature silicone](http://www.clearcoproducts.com/pdf/bath-fluids/NP-DPDM-400-High-Temperature-Silicone-Bath-Fluid.pdf) to 250°C, then drop in your foil wrapped paper.